# How can I open a kmz file with Google's GEplugin?

Tags: c#, kml, google-earth-plugin, kmz, sharpkml

I've opened a kml file with sharpkml and GEplugin 
but I was wondering how to open a kmz file with it.

Anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do it using sharpkml but the GE plugin API includes the function fetchKml to load kml and kmz files.

Below is the code (from [code samples playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=earth#fetch_good_kml): I changed the link to use an example kmz file from [this](http://code.google.com/p/kml-samples/) sample page.)

var url = 'http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/kml/Region/GroundOverlay/usa-ca-sf.kmz';

google.earth.fetchKml(ge, url, finished);

Using the winforms geplugin library I use the wrapper function FetchKml:
geWebBrowser1.FetchKml("http://" + sServerIP + "//sample.kmz");